# Advantages of XML based Datasets over ordinary Datasets

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, dataset

I'm learning XML usage from a book. But stumbling upon a few things. Well I know XML has got increasing technology demands like in Web Services and stuff. They are human readable, hierarchical. But as I came across a topic in which Datasets were being populated through XML (using `Microsoft.Data.SqlXml` namespace which exposes classes (such as`SqlXmlCommand` and `SqlXmlAdapter)` analogous to `SqlCommand` , `SqlDataAdapter`).
 I couldn't make out why would any one use those exposed classes(`SqlXmlCommand`, `SqlXmlDataAdapter`) when we have ADO.Net classes to query database and populate our Dataset? Sometimes it XML stuff here appears to be an overhead. Or may be I'm overlooking the aspects?

Following is an excerpt from the book using Xml(XPath) based Dataset, which has an overhead of creating an XSD schema file.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   cmd = new SqlXmlCommand(strConn);
   cmd.RootTag = "ROOT";
   cmd.CommandText = "Employees";
   cmd.CommandType = SqlXmlCommandType.XPath;
   cmd.SchemaPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\employees.xsd"; // Overhead
   ds = new DataSet();
   da = new SqlXmlAdapter(cmd);
   da.Fill(ds);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   da.Update(ds);
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using.  Are you required to use Net2.0 (foundation) or can you use later (if c#)?  ADO is usually associated with an Access Database so are you using Access?   The SQLXmlCommand contains the SQL query of the database and the connection.  The SqlXmlDataAdapter will automatically fill a data table in one instruction so it can be displayed in the datagridview1.

Comment: SqlXmlCommand could not just contain SQL query but others like XPath depending upon SqlXmlCommandType enumeration. SqlDataAdapter also require just one instruction to 'populate' Data Table. Then what's the point in recruiting SqlXmlAdapter?

Comment: SqlDataAdapter is for an SQL Server database.  I can't tell from posted code what SqlXmlAdapter is using.  I assume it is a custom Class.  The System.Data library implements a number of different classes for connecting to different type databases like SQLClient( SQL Server), Odbc, Oledb (there is also an Oracle, and a My SQL Server).  All these databases interface inherit the same base class.  With the code posted I can't tell the actual database.

Comment: I know that. Agreed! But I am interested in knowing: This Xml stuff with these data set seems to be an overhead (writing schema, Xml based queries etc). However, It is required in web services but, by far I have seen that such complexities are dealt by the services under the hood for which we don't have to worry. I'm not able to figure out how could it be useful for us while we are developing

Comment: The real question is how does the service check the validity of the data values before sending the message to the clients.  Suppose a value is null.  Is it quicker to check each value or have the schema perform the checking.  What is nice about a schema is you can change the schema without recompiling.